# How to take value from input field who's value is taken from an angular controller

Tags: angularjs, forms

Actually i am retrieving data from BD and showing it in p element as below:

```
<p>{{customerDetailData.Name}}</p>
```

but i want to take this data as the value of the input field in form, as like below:

```
<input type="text" id="businessname"  name="businessname"  ng-model="data.businessname" ng-value="customerDetailData.Name" >
```

It's taking the value from input field but only if i am doing any modification in that input field but it's not taking that value if i left that field as it.

Please help me, Thanks

Comment: but i want to take this data as the value of the input field in form, as like below: 

<input type="text" id="businessname"  name="businessname"  ng-model="data.businessname" ng-value="customerDetailData.Name" >

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the value of `data.businessname` variable in the controller with the value of `customerDetailData.Name` and the ng-value attribute will not be needed anymore.

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13589/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init="data.businessname=customerDetailData.Name" as below code.

```
<input type="text" id="businessname"  name="businessname" ng-init="data.businessname=customerDetailData.Name"  ng-model="data.businessname" ng-value="customerDetailData.Name" />
```